# VS2010 Disable T4 Template Validation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, preprocessor, t4, directive

How do you disable **T4 Template validation** . VS2010 is validating my T4 Template just now on ever part that has '#' (the sharp character).

```
error CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line
```

The error is nonsense. I can even generate code from my templates but I can't run my project because my templates throw error **CS1040.**

I get this error after installing visual t4, even uninstalling from extensions manager won't work. Installing Visual T4 for VS2010 gave me problems with subsonic templates. disabling and uninstalling didn't help either. I am so disappointed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For some reasons "Build Action" for T4 templates changed to 'compile' just set it back to 'content'

Answer (score 1):

The build action of your T4 template has changed. This may happen when you have copied your files from one project to another, or changed it in the properties by accident.

Steps to resolve it:

- Right-click the file and choose **Properties** (Alt+Enter).
- Select **Build Action** and change it to the default value **None**.
- Save the project and rebuild.